# Power bi datasets

Tags: powerbi, dataset

Guys this is a bit of newbie question. Ive tried to google it and understand how they work but im not having much luck.  I have a datasets created by colleague that connect to one of our systems.

I want to look at using it and trying to make some changes.  I can see Its create a .pibx file when i saved a copy of the dataset. i want to look at model section and see if i can pull some further fields(column) into table on the dataset that already links some corresponding data from two other tables.  Id like to add more fields(columns) that are not currently in that table

However i don't want to affect other datasets and or the data on the system it is communicating with.

Can anyone advise me if this is the case.

As i really only want to test things for now and not make any changes that might affect other people

Answer (score 0):

You can create duplicate for original table( Query ) then play with that duplicat